# Dynamic Sharing Rules Based on Formula Work Around

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

I have 4 custom objects I'm using that are all set to private - Project Location, Project, Field Items & Materials.

I have multiple Roles that need access to all these records depending on if they are in the associated country.

The country is set on the Project Location record.

Initially, I set up formulas on the 3 other custom objects to pull in the relevant Country so I could then create Custom Sharing rules on the 3 custom objects so they're shared with the correct Role (segmented by Country).

Sharing Rules cannot use Formulas as a criteria point.

I've now attempted to create a WFR on the Project object to set a custom field with the country to fire whenever the Country on the Project Location changes.

I'm getting this issue: Error: Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula

Has anyone done found a workaround, or accomplished something simular?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show us the workflow you've created?

Comment: It would also be useful to see the schema you're working with. Is Project Location the Parent of the other three objects? If so, is it possible to create a master-detail relationship? If you have a master-detail relationship, the child objects will inherit the sharing rules of the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this error is coming because the evaluation criteria selected is :

**created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria**

[image]

Choose the evaluation criteria as

**created, and every time it's edited**

and then you should be able to use ISCHANGED
[image]